# Discriminate union type of a child property

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure if the title is correct.

But is there a way to not allow the union type, but make it more specific to only allow a specific interface?

See the following example:

```js
interface Buz {
  buz: string;
}

interface Qux {
  qux: boolean;
}

export interface FooBar {
  content?: Buz | Qux;
}

const somethingBuz: FooBar = {
  content: {
    buz: 'yay!',
    qux: true // <- this should not be allowed
  }
}

const somethingQux: FooBar = {
  content: {
    buz: 'yay', // <- this should not be allowed
    qux: true
  }
}
```

Comment: TypeScript currently does not have exact types. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936. An object can always be augmented dynamically at runtime, which is why a TypeScript type means the value has *at least* the specified properties, but it may have more.

Comment: Your union is not discrimininated. It does not have a discriminant property that is of a literal type

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate. This is a different use-case since this is more about a _nested_ property. I have also found a potential answer which perhaps better explains the difference.

Comment: Omit<FooBar, 'content'> & { content: Buz }